# Angular RxJS: Do I need to do .takeUntil(this.destroy$) if I'm using async pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

If I have an element in my template which is using property binding, bound to an observable, using `async` pipe to ensure it is unsubscribed automatically...then would using `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` be unnecessary?

Template snippet:

```
<input name="SomeElement"
    [ngModel]="boundObservable$ | async">
</input>
```

Component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  boundObservable$ = this.sourceObservable$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    map(this.transformData)
  );

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }    
}
```

Comment: Yes.  async pipe will do unsubscribe, if the component is destroyed. You dont need the takeUntil operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR -** No need for that because the `async` pipe does that automatically when the component gets destroyed.

**The details**

As mentioned in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description):

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
> latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
> pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
> gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
> potential memory leaks.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9b8f056604891537e37d6e0231b28b99868bd041/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L92) of how the `async` pipe is handling it:

```js
  // Create Subscription: _subscribe is called from the pipe's `transform` function:
  private _subscribe(obj: Subscribable<any>|Promise<any>|EventEmitter<any>): void {
    this._obj = obj;
    this._strategy = this._selectStrategy(obj);
    this._subscription = this._strategy.createSubscription(
        obj, (value: Object) => this._updateLatestValue(obj, value));
  }

  // Dispose Subscription:
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._dispose();
    }
  }

  private _dispose(): void {
    this._strategy.dispose(this._subscription!);
    this._latestValue = null;
    this._subscription = null;
    this._obj = null;
  }
```

Where the used strategy is one of two classes that implement the [SubscriptionStrategy](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9b8f056604891537e37d6e0231b28b99868bd041/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L14) interface:

```js
interface SubscriptionStrategy {
  createSubscription(async: Subscribable<any>|Promise<any>, updateLatestValue: any): Unsubscribable
      |Promise<any>;
  dispose(subscription: Unsubscribable|Promise<any>): void;
  onDestroy(subscription: Unsubscribable|Promise<any>): void;
}

class SubscribableStrategy implements SubscriptionStrategy {
  createSubscription(async: Subscribable<any>, updateLatestValue: any): Unsubscribable {
    return async.subscribe({
      next: updateLatestValue,
      error: (e: any) => {
        throw e;
      }
    });
  }

  dispose(subscription: Unsubscribable): void {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onDestroy(subscription: Unsubscribable): void {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

class PromiseStrategy implements SubscriptionStrategy {
  createSubscription(async: Promise<any>, updateLatestValue: (v: any) => any): Promise<any> {
    return async.then(updateLatestValue, e => {
      throw e;
    });
  }

  dispose(subscription: Promise<any>): void {}

  onDestroy(subscription: Promise<any>): void {}
}
```